How to stop the cursor from jumping out of parentheses/brackets/braces
I am having an issue that is seriously impacting my ability to fluently write code in wolframnotebook 14.1.
Whenever my cursor is just behind an opening bracket/parenthesis/brace, it automatically jumps in front of it. (See attached video)
I am thinking there must be a preference-setting that i can turn off, but i have not found which one yet.
If anyone knows the name of this feature, i would be very grateful!


Welcome to Mathematica StackExchange! This indeed looks very weird, and it does not happen to me. Which operating system are you using? What if you go to Edit > Preferences > Interface and uncheck Automatically insert matching delimiters? Have you tried resetting Mathematica? If nothing helps, I think you should write to the technical support ...

Don't you use some kind of weird custom font instead of default one? The font can cause shifting of the apparent position of the cursor compared to its true position.
